# How to debug blender freezing the whole computer?

Tags: gpu, linux

I am trying to use Blender on a laptop with the following specs:

- Intel Xeon E3-1200
- HD Graphics 520
- 16 GB RAM
- Debian (linux) OS

I don't expect it working fast nor handling big scenes (I'm just starting to learn), but that seems above [the requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). Despite that, I am observing Blender freezing the whole computer every 15-30min. When it freezes, it often flickers with the previous frame or two of what was shown in blender.

I don't see a correlation between what I'm doing and when it crashes: I saw it crash both when using Eevee and Cycles, doing heavy stuff (generating fire) or duplicating a small mesh or increasing the size of the brush.

I looked at things like RAM, CPU usage, and free space on disk, but all seemed fine. I also looked at the forums didn't find any solution. I tried using both 2.93.1 (downloaded as a binary from blender page) and 2.83.1 from the repo.

I ran blender with `--debug-all` and `--verbose 1` but the generated logs didn't tell me much. Here are the logs: [debug](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IOv8sZa_JAbOQGdiOe__V8e0H5r8Ap8r/view?usp=sharing), [verbose](https://paste.ofcode.org/LVFyVXpKeexwTjeiPavEWi), [glxinfo](https://pastebin.com/TDurEjrR).

How can I debug this issue further?

Answer (score 2):

There are some *Debug* files that when run just print logs/errors/etc into some text files.

Go to your blender's directory:

> C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93

(or whatever it is)

These should be located there:

> blender_debug_log.cmd

> blender_debug_gpu.cmd

> blender_debug_gpu_glitchworkaround.cmd

Open them and Blender starts by showing a prompt to you that opens Blender's environment just after pressing a key.

Blender now saves a log file in your temp folder after your exit/crash

> C:\Users\ *username* \AppData\Local\Temp\blender\debug_logs

I hope these help.

Comment: Thanks, these don't exist in a linux OS

Comment: Is the whole OS crashing? If so, does Linux have OS crash logs?